# finding old cookies from Chrome

Tags: research

so I was using chrome to do research on subatomic particles and the website got taken down so I'm on my C Drive under the path users username app that a local Google Chrome user data default and there are just a lot of folders and files I was just wondering which one of these files or folders could I open and using what software to read the articles that I have no access to

Comment: Cookies would just be the key/value pairs that a website pushed down on you.  If you want to read web pages, you'd want to be looking at the cache ... and with that note, I really think this would be a better fit for http://SuperUser.stackexchange.com , as it's really about how to do something in Chrome.

Comment: @Joe I rejected the migration to [su] because it ended up on our meta, could you re-migrate it to our main site so we get a clear migration path? Cheers!

Comment: @Mokubai : I typed 'superuser.stackexchange.com' into the site to migrate it to.  I have no idea why it went to meta.  (it expanded to meta when I first just typed only 'superuser').  I guess I have to wait for a list to appear (which took a good 60 sec or so)